# Jquery append to a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

In my vue.js project I've this template:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="!isEmpty(media)">
        <div class="flex wrap">            
            <div v-for="file in media" :key="file.id" @click.prevent="action(file)">
                <div>
                    <a href="/file/93">
                        <img v-bind:src="fileType(file.file_name)" class="media-file" :alt="file.name" :title="file.name"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-if="context == 'destroy'">
            <p>Klik op het bestand om deze te verwijderen.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Just for testing porpoises I've hardcoded `<a href="/file/93">`.

Now when someone clicks on the image `action(file)` is triggered.

Here I append a couple of things with jquery like this:

```
alert('test');
$('<a href="/file/93">')
    .attr('data-lightbox','roadtrip')
    .append('<img src="/file/93">')
    .addClass('test');
```

But nothing happens when I inspect the a tag in chrome. What am I doing wrong here? The alert pops up so that's not the problem. `Jquery` is working aswel I've checked that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('<a href="/file/93">')` does not select the `a` element that you have. I think it rather creates a new DOM element that is eventually never attached to the document.

In order to select an element through an attribute value, you could do:
`$('[href="/file/93"]')`